# How can I configure Backup Alert in Recovery Service Vault using ARM Template?

Tags: azure, azure-site-recovery

Hi I am trying to add Backup Alert to Recovery Service Vault, but I will like to use IaC instead of adding it via Portal. Is there a way this can be done by ARM Templates?

Answer (score 0):

Alerts are primarily scenarios where users are notified so that they can take relevant action. The [Backup Alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-monitoring-built-in-monitor#backup-alerts-in-recovery-services-vault) section shows alerts **generated** by Azure Backup service.

The following scenarios are defined by service as alertable scenarios:

- Backup/Restore failures
- Backup succeeded with warnings for Microsoft Azure Recovery Services (MARS) agent
- Stop protection with retain data/Stop protection with delete data

Please note that these alerts are defined by the service and **user can't custom create any alerts**.